# How to get runtime app permission using Android Management API?

Tags: android-management-api

I am using Android Management API to get the list of app permissions.

**API**: https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.applications/get

**Response Body**: https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.applications#ApplicationPermission

It is returning all the permissions without any categorization (like runtime, normal, special, etc.) that are associated with the application for which we have requested.

I want to filter out only runtime permissions from the provided response.

Is there any way to get the permission details along with the type of permission it is in Android Management API?

Sample Data that I am getting for the Gmail app:

```
{
  "name": "enterprises/xxxxxxxxxx/applications/com.google.android.gm",
  "title": "Gmail",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "permissionId": "android.permission.BLUETOOTH",
      "name": "pair with Bluetooth devices",
      "description": "Allows the app to view the configuration of Bluetooth on the device, and to make and accept connections with paired devices."
    },
    {
      "permissionId": "android.permission.CALL_PHONE",
      "name": "directly call phone numbers",
      "description": "Allows the app to call phone numbers without your intervention. This may result in unexpected charges or calls. Note that this doesn't allow the app to call emergency numbers. Malicious apps may cost you money by making calls without your confirmation."
    },
    {
      "permissionId": "android.permission.CAMERA",
      "name": "take pictures and videos",
      "description": "Allows the app to take pictures and videos with the camera. This permission allows the app to use the camera at any time without your confirmation."
    },
    {
      "permissionId": "android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS",
      "name": "use accounts on the device",
      "description": "Allows the app to request authentication tokens."
    },
    {
      "permissionId": "android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS",
      "name": "modify your contacts",
      "description": "Allows the app to modify the data about your contacts stored on your device, including the frequency with which you've called, emailed, or communicated in other ways with specific contacts. This permission allows apps to delete contact data."
    },
    {
      "permissionId": "com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES",
      "name": "read Google service configuration",
      "description": "Allows this app to read Google service configuration data."
    },
    {
      "permissionId": "com.google.android.voicesearch.AUDIO_FILE_ACCESS"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you point out in your question, applications.get returns all the permissions of the app but it doesn’t indicate the protection level or group of the permission.  It would be possible to leverage the permission api [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission) and filter out the items which are marked with the ‘dangerous’ protection level, as those permissions would require runtime approval.  Please keep in mind that runtime approval is based on [permission groups](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group) and that granting permission for any member of a permission group would apply for all members within that group.

For example: If an application requests both READ_CONTACTS and WRITE_CONTACTS, but the [PermissionGrant](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#permissiongrant) supplied within the device’s policy only included a GRANT permission for READ_CONTACTS, the application would be granted access to all permissions within the [Contacts](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group#CONTACTS) group, which includes both READ_CONTACTS and WRITE_CONTACTS permissions.